# Interactive map suggestion

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone suggest technology to make interactive map effect like this site?

[Subito](http://www.subito.it/)

Any suggestion except flash, cause this site don't using it?

Comment: Inspect the page in your browser with Firebug or Developer Tools (depends on the browser). You'll see they use `<map>` and `<area>` along with some Javascript events to animate/change things

Comment: Yes i see that, need some more explanation about that.

Comment: @StefanCvetkovic Stack Overflow is for specific questions, don't expect to get a full tutorial here...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/area

Comment: I dont ask for full tutorial, i need suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [d3.js](http://d3js.org) it is a nice framework for visualizations.

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) is an example of how you can use it for maps.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't support older browsers like IE 8 - not so good if you plan to use this on a public site.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the page with your browser, you'll see that they use an [image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map), with map and area tags to draw the map.

Another way would be [to use svg](http://www.google.com/search?num=20&hl=en&q=svg%20map) (usually together with vml for cross-browser compatibility). Examples of such solutions are [Google geocharts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?hl=pt-BR) and [dojo](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGeoCharting/demo.html).

Comment: Thanks mate i will experiment.